# Targeting Windows Outlook Desktop Client

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm designing an HTML email. It's going relatively well, except for Outlook, as expected. The web-based Outlooks are fine, but I need to target the Outlook desktop clients.

I've tried variations of this code below, but it just outputs that code above the newsletter, thus failing to use it:

```
<!--[if mso]
<style type="text/css">
  #strip, #wrap, #header, #main_cont, #footer, #footer_content{ width: 600px !important; }
  #main_cont{ width: 600px !important; } 
  #side{ width: 196px !important; }
  #main{ width: 400px !important; } 
</style>
![endif]-->
```

I've also tried 'max-device-width' instead of width, but to no avail. Here's what the test screen outputs in all Outlook desktop clients: http://www.epicuploader.com/13_12_zaBlRga.jpg

I just want the Windows Outlook desktop version (Mac is fine) to render at 600px in width with the main_cont, side, and main divs to render properly as instructed too. I've looked through other topics on here, but none seem to address this particular problem.

I'm using Mailchimp too.

Comment: with Jarno's fix, check your email source code in Outlook (`r.click>view source` at the bottom of the html in the preview window). Is the style tag rendering? Sometimes MS Exchange servers can strip the style tags...

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot a `>` after `<!--[if mso]` and a `<` before `![endif]-->`:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
#strip, #wrap, #header, #main_cont, #footer, #footer_content{ width: 600px !important; }
#main_cont{ width: 600px !important; } 
#side{ width: 196px !important; }
#main{ width: 400px !important; } 
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed that and the code no longer outputs at the top, but the IE-specific changes still don't take effect.

Comment: That's the problem I've had with the Outlook client as well. No matter what I do to exclude Outlook from my REAL code and then feed IT code specifically designed to work inside its idiocies, it reads both, spits out both, and wrecks the email template.  I am really really angry and frustrated to the point I want to just flat out power kick Micro$uck's CEO in the balls over this. (Just venting -- I would not literally resort to actual criminal assault on anyone no matter how angry I feel.)

Comment: If anyone knows what the magic bullet is to deliver a responsive email template that feeds Outlook the crap code it needs AND conceals all the real (good) code from it, please enlighten me.  I've literally tried this a dozen different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the Outlook version i.e.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Your Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

See [here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) for more details regarding versions (9 is Outlook 2000).